# Magento 2 How to get first level parent category of current Category?

Tags: magento2, category, category-view, magento-2.1.9

I want to get the **first level `parent category`** of the **current category**. I have a code but it gets only the **parent of the current category**:

```
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,      
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getParentCategory()
    {
        if($this->getCurrentCategory()):
            if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()):
                  $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getId();
            endif;
        endif;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use to `getParentCategories()` to collect all parent categories, then loop check with level.

```
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,      
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getLevel1Category(){
        if($this->getCurrentCategory()){
            if($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories()){
                foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
                    if ($parent->getLevel() == 1) {
                        // reurns the level 1 category id;
                        return $parent->getId();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

if above methods not worked means you can go with `getpath()` then explode the path with '/'. you will get the root parent category.

i hope this will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: I will make a small addition if possible. The method `getParentCategories` is not public API of `CategoryInterface`. If you need to use only API and increase upgradability of your module, you can add service, which will use `CategoryInterface::getPath` and `CategoryRepositoryInterface::getLIst` with id = parent_ids and level=1 criteria. In this case, you will use only `API` of Catalog module without private part.

Comment: yes sure max,  interesting add a detail answers, its really helps me and others who learn magento2

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $parCatId = $category->getId(); // current Category ID
    $parCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parCatId);
    $parent_category = $parCategory->getParentCategory();
    $catName = $parent_category->getName();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($catName);
    echo "<pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
)
{
    $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
}

public function getCategoryCollection($categoryId){
    $categoryFactory = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $category = $categoryFactory->load($categoryId);

    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('eq' => 1));
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: This code gives current category id. I want to get top level parent category id

Comment: Please review my update above.

Comment: invalid variable, $collection